# How I can secure My lti Tool in canvas lms using the same access_token given by instance?

Tags: security, canvas, lti

I created an external application and integrate it in canvas lms,and I want it to use the same access_token as issued by the Oauth2 idp in canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both LTI 1.3 and the CanvasLMS Api use OAuth2 tokens, the tokens have different uses and scopes, and so you can not use the same token for both LTI application integration and private API access.

You can read more about creating an [LTI1.3 Developer Token in the canvas api documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.tools_intro.html).

Comment: thank you your response,I'll check the link.